# Divergence of a power series

Tags: power-series, divergent-series

Let $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb N} \subset \mathbb R$ be a series so that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ has convergence radius R. Suppose

$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n R^n = \infty
$$
holds. Does it follow that

$$
\lim_{(-R, R) \ni x \rightarrow R} \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n = \infty?
$$

My intuition tells me this should be the case, but sadly I have no idea how to prove this. (It took me quite a while to get that result for a certain series $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ and now I wonder, whether I could have used a general result instead.)

Comment: If all (or all but finitely many) $a_n$ are non-negative, it's easy. If you have both, infinitely many negative $a_n$, and infinitely many positive $a_n$, it's once again easy if $\sum a_n^- R^n < +\infty$ (where $a_n^-$ is the negative part of $a_n$, $0$ if $a_n \geqslant 0$, and $\lvert a_n\rvert$ if $a_n < 0$). If that's not the case and you just have $$\lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{n = 0}^N a_n R^n = +\infty,$$ it'll be more delicate. What situation have you, and would you be happy with less than full generality if that suffices for your immediate purposes?

Comment: If $a_n \ge 0$ for all (or all but finitely many) $a_n$, then I could use the monotone convergence theorem, couldn‘t I? (If that is not what you meant with “easy”, I would be interested in the easy/elementary proof was well.

Comment: However I am also curious about the more general case.

Comment: Yes, monotone convergence, or quite elementarily cutting off the series (behind the last negative $a_n$), then for $0 < x < R$ you have $$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_n x^n \geqslant \sum_{n = 0}^N a_n x^n,$$ and therefore $$\liminf_{x \to R} \sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_n x^n \geqslant \liminf_{x\to R} \sum_{n = 0}^N a_n x^n = \sum_{n = 0}^N a_n R^n.$$ Then let $N \to \infty$ to get the result. If the negative part of the series is summable, basically the same argument works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can modify the proof of [Abel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel's_theorem) to deal with this situation. First, if necessary replace $a_n$ with $a_n R^n$ to get $R = 1$, which simplifies the notation but doesn't change anything important. Then denote

$$f(x) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_n x^n\quad \text{for } x \in (-1,1)\quad\text{and}\quad s_n = \sum_{k = 0}^n a_k.$$

For $x \in (-1,1)$ we have

$$F(x) := \frac{f(x)}{1-x} = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty s_n x^n.$$

Now, given an arbitrary $M \in (0,+\infty)$, choose $N \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $s_n > M$ for all $n \geqslant N$. Then we can split the power series of $F$ at $N$ to obtain

\begin{align}
f(x) &= (1-x)F(x) \\
&= (1-x)\sum_{n = 0}^{N-1} s_n x^n + (1 - x)\sum_{n = N}^\infty s_n x^n \\
&\geqslant (1 - x)\sum_{n = N}^\infty s_n x^n - (1 - x)\sum_{n = 0}^{N-1} \lvert a_n x^n\rvert \\
&> (1 - x)\sum_{n = N}^\infty M x^n - (1- x)\sum_{n = 0}^{N-1} \lvert a_n\rvert \\
&= M\cdot x^N - (1 - x) \sum_{n = 0}^{N-1} \lvert a_n\rvert.
\end{align}

From this inequality, we obtain

$$\liminf_{x \to 1^-} f(x) \geqslant M,$$

since $x^N \to 1$, and $\sum_{n = 0}^{N-1} \lvert a_n\rvert$ is a fixed quantity. Since $M$ was arbitrary, it follows that

$$\lim_{x \to 1^-} f(x) = +\infty = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_n.$$

Comment: Sorry for my late reply and thanks for your answer. Why is $F(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty s_n x^n$?

Comment: Two ways to see it. You can start with the definition $F(x):=\dfrac{f(x)}{1-x}$, expand $f(x)$ and $\dfrac{1}{1-x}$ into their Maclaurin series and multiply, $$\Biggl(\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n\Biggr)\cdot\Biggl(\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_kx^k\Biggr)=\sum_{n,k=0}^\infty a_nc_kx^{n+k}=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\Biggl(\sum_{n=0}^m a_nc_{m-n}\Biggr)x^m,$$and with $c_k=1$ for all $k$ for $\dfrac{1}{1-x}$, you see that the coefficients in the last series are $s_m$. Or you start defining $F(x):=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty s_nx^n$ and multiply out $(1-x)\cdot F(x)$ which results in $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n=f(x)$.

Comment: Oh, of course. Thanks. :)